# Scala Apache Spark: Nonstandard characters in column names

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm calling the following:

```
  propertiesDF.select(
        col("timestamp"), col("coordinates")(0) as "lon", 
        col("coordinates")(1) as "lat", 
        col("properties.tide (above mllw)") as "tideAboveMllw",
        col("properties.wind speed") as "windSpeed")
```

This gives me the following error:

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: No such struct field tide
>   (above mllw) in air temperature, atmospheric pressure, dew point,
>   dominant wave period, mean wave direction, name, program name,
>   significant wave height, tide (above mllw):, visibility, water
>   temperature, wind direction, wind speed;

Now there definitely is such a struct field.  (The error message itself says so.)

Here is the schema:

```
 root
 |-- timestamp: long (nullable = true)
 |-- coordinates: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
 |-- properties: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- air temperature: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- atmospheric pressure: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- dew point: double (nullable = true)
          .
          .
          .
 |    |-- tide (above mllw):: string (nullable = true)
          .
          .
          .
```

The input is read as JSON like this:

```
val df = sqlContext.read.json(dirName)
```

How do I handle parentheses in a column name?

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid names like this in the first place but you can either split access path:

```
val df = spark.range(1).select(struct(
  lit(123).as("tide (above mllw)"),
  lit(1).as("wind speed")
).as("properties"))

df.select(col("properties").getItem("tide (above mllw)"))

// or

df.select(col("properties")("tide (above mllw)"))
```

or enclose problematic field with backticks:

```
df.select(col("properties.`tide (above mllw)`"))
```

Both solutions assume data your data contains following structure (based on the access path you use for queries):

```
df.printSchema
// root
//  |-- properties: struct (nullable = false)
//  |    |-- tide (above mllw): integer (nullable = false)
//  |    |-- wind speed: integer (nullable = false)
```

Comment: Your first solution is giving me this error:

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: No such struct field tide (above mllw) in air temperature, atmospheric pressure, dew point, dominant wave period, mean wave direction, name, program name, significant wave height, tide (above mllw):, visibility, water temperature, wind direction, wind speed

Comment: Your second solution is giving me this error: Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: No such struct field tide (above mllw) in air temperature, atmospheric pressure, dew point, dominant wave period, mean wave direction, name, program name, significant wave height, tide (above mllw):, visibility, water temperature, wind direction, wind speed;

Comment: Your third solution is giving me this error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: No such struct field tide (above mllw) in air temperature, atmospheric pressure, dew point, dominant wave period, mean wave direction, name, program name, significant wave height, tide (above mllw):, visibility, water temperature, wind direction, wind speed;

Comment: There seems to be additional `:` after `tide (above mllw): ` Is it a typo?

Comment: It's just ellipses to show that there are more fields.  It's not a typo.

Comment: It is not what I mean additional colon in the name.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [the documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/escape_char_r.html) you might try with single quotes. Like this:

```
 propertiesDF.select(
        col("timestamp"), col("coordinates")(0) as "lon", 
        col("coordinates")(1) as "lat", 
        col("'properties.tide (above mllw)'") as "tideAboveMllw",
        col("properties.wind speed") as "windSpeed")
```

Comment: Your suggestion is giving me this error:

org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot resolve column name "'properties.tide (above mllw)'" among (timestamp, coordinates, properties)

Comment: Ok, sorry. TBH I wasn't even able to reproduce the error in the first place.