# How to specify a column with non alphanumeric characters in spark sql

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

`DataStax Enterprise Graph` includes a column `~label` that we need work with: here is a specific SQL statement:

```sql
select phoneId as id, phoneId, 'phone' as ~label from phones
```

Spark SQL will not handle this automatically:

```
extraneous input '~' expecting {<EOF>, ',', 'FROM', 'WHERE', 'GROUP', 'ORDER', 'HAVING', 'LIMIT', 'LATERAL', 'WINDOW', 'UNION', 'EXCEPT', 'MINUS', 'INTERSECT', 'SORT', 'CLUSTER', 'DISTRIBUTE'}(line 1, pos 42)

== SQL ==
   select phoneId as id, phoneId, 'phone' as ~label from phones
------------------------------------------^^^
```

How can we work with this non alphanumeric column name?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala Apache Spark: Parentheses in column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38856240/scala-apache-spark-parentheses-in-column-names)

Comment: How is someone who is searching for "non alphanumeric characters" going to *find* that question - which only mentions "parentheses" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick here turns out to enclose the column name in `backtick`'s:

```
 select phoneId as id, phoneId, 'phone' as `~label` from phones
```